# Autowiring ApplicationContext in Spring Webflux while writing junit test case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I am trying to write junit for the controller class which is written using spring webflux.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(SecurityApiHandler.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SecurityApiRouter.class, SecurityApiHandler.class })
public class SecurityApiHandlerTest {

@Autowired
private static ApplicationContext context;

private static WebTestClient webTestClient;

@MockBean
private SecurityApiService securityService;

@BeforeAll
public static void setUp() {
    webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
}

@Test
public void healthCheckTest() {
    webTestClient.get().uri("/health-check").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).exchange().expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody(HealthCheck.class).value(response -> {
            Assertions.assertThat(response.getApiName()).isEqualTo("security-service");
        });
}

}
```

I am following this article to write my test case: https://blog.knoldus.com/spring-webflux-testing-your-router-functions-with-webtestclient/

ApplicationContext is not getting autowired due to which I am getting error **IllegalArgumentException: ApplicationContext is required**

Comment: autowiring doesn't work on static fields and you should just inject the `WebTestClient` spring boot can do the setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks it worked. Please post it as an answer.